# Jqgrid - formatter and unformat with celledit:true not working

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I've created my own number formatter and unformat method, but when I click on the cell to edit it and fill with a number, the cellvalue parameter comes empty. The default types of formatter also doesn't work.

How can I deal with edit field format?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct your problem you should use [formatCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) callback.

Comment: Actually formatter and unformat seems to be enough to have the data in the right format, but the afterEditCell and formatCell methods are getting the original value instead of the edit field value.